# hibernate initial session creation failed

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am building an application with hibernate 4.3.10. I have setup each and everything but connection between database is not establishing.here is my configuration file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=HibernatePractice</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">NAWAL\SQLEXPRESS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My hibernateUtil file

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static SessionFactory setSession() {
          try {
           // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
              Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
              configuration.configure();
              StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
              serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
              ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
           return sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
          }

          catch (Throwable ex) {
           // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
           System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed.");
           throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
          }

         }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        sessionFactory = setSession();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

and i am getting this error.

```
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] at URL [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=HibernatePractice]
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=NAWAL\SQLEXPRESS, password=****}
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 28, 2015 5:27:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at HibernateUtil.setSession(HibernateUtil.java:25)
    at HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:31)
    at Actions.main(Actions.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at HibernateUtil.setSession(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'NAWAL\SQLEXPRESS'. ClientConnectionId:1b0c2212-8381-4e47-a49a-b6a6c886e6c1
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 15 more
```

I have added all the files of required folder of hibernate distribution bundle, sqljdbc4.jar as well. Plus i wanna know that do i have to build database and tables in sql server management myself or this application will build itself? I am new to hibernate.

Comment: The message says: *Login failed for user 'NAWAL\SQLEXPRESS'*. So it's a user/password problem. Not a Hibernate problem.

Comment: yeah what could be the possible reason for that? do you have any idea?

Comment: A wrong user, a wrong password, or both.

Comment: My servername is NAWAL\SQLEXPRESS and it doesnt have any password. so i left it blank. my sql server management studio connects with these properties

Comment: i have never used this database, so I am not sure, but that is one interesting username. Can you try and escape the `\` in the username. Also first try to connect with the `root` account to check if its problem with connection or just your credentials.